# Issue with for loop and list generation

Tags: r, list, for-loop, ggplot2

This is probably a simple problem but I am struggling with it. I am trying to use a for loop to generate density plots for each column in my data frame. I am able to create a list from the column names but when I try to use that list I am unable to generate my density plots.

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(mtcars)

list <- colnames(df1[1:11])

for (i in list){
    ggdensity(df1$i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works, but `ggdensity` will not print the plot without a function to do so inside the loop.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

list <- colnames(mtcars)

for (i in list){
  ggdensity(mtcars[,i]) 
}
```

A `tidyverse` solution that might help you

```
mtcars %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value))+
  geom_density()+
  facet_wrap(~name,scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe good to note that when using `$`-subsetting, the part after `$` is interpreted as a string. In the OP case, this results in a NULL, as there is no column called `i` in mtcars. Indeed using `[]`-subsetting solves this issue.

Comment: @MartijnVanAttekum I tried using 

for (i in list){
  ggdensity(mtcars$[i]) 
}

but that did not take care of the issue either. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @ViniciusFelix if I use something like 

`ggdensity(df1$carb)`

or

`ggdensity(df1[,1]`

The code works for single plots but not when put into a for loop, so while the tidyverse example is a fantastic work around, I am still not understanding why the two examples in this response do not work in a for loop

Comment: @Patchhr33 The subsetting should be just `mtcars[,i]` as @ViniciusFelix also does, but as he also points out, using the `for` loop will calculate the plots, but not print them.